# Cast timestamp with intval() change the int to 2147483647

Tags: javascript, php

In my app, i sending from Javascript to PHP a variable which is a timestamp. For example, from javascript i send this var :

```
var date = new Date().getTime();   //(date = 1474119172775)
```

When i retrieve this date in my php, i do a intval() to be sure to cast the value to int before storing in my sql database.

But when i do this, i get the following result :

```
$dateFrom = intval($json['date']);  // ($dateFrom = 2147483647)
```

I see on PHP doc that intval function can return this value for 32 bits system, so what can i use to cast my input var into an int ?

Comment: Divide by 1000 on clien as it is milliseconds

Comment: Or just slice it as string: `substr(..., 0, -3)`

Comment: `intval` and `(int)` have basically no difference.

Answer (score 1):

AS timestamp on client provided by `getTime` is in **milliseconds** (seconds multipled by 1000), you have to pass it like:

```
var date = (new Date().getTime()) / 1000;
```

And change nothing on server side.

Comment: I tried to do this, but my date is now stored in this format for example : 1474120752 instead of 1474120752000 . And we i get back in javascript this date (1474120752), i am not able to create a valid date. I have also to multiplicate * 1000 in javascript ?

Comment: Yes, you surely do.